# Installing windows gadget fails

Tags: windows, windows-desktop-gadgets

At least I finished developing a new windows gadget.
I zipped it and removed the ".zip", so that it's a valid ".gadget"-file now.
When I execute this file the install-dialog pops up, i click "install" but nothing happens.. Any suggestions? When i copy the extracted (not zipped) Windows gadget into "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets", I can use it successfully, but the way I descriped before isn't possible..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have zipped up one folder too many.

If you zipped up "gadget_name.gadget" then, if you executed this it would not install.
You need to go into the gadget.gadget folder and zip up them files. For example in that folder you may have 2 folder labeled EN-US and Images. you need to zip them up from there and when save them as "gadget_name.gadget", change the extension from .zip to .gadget.

It may be a late reply but it might be helpful.

Comment: This was my problem. So, for instance, the .zip file (renamed .gadget) should have a 'Gadget.xml' file in it at the root level, not in a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Check there are no empty folders in your gadget zip.

Also ensure you have the correct Directory structure Eg,

```
mygadget.gadget\gadget.xml
```

Not

```
mygadget.gadget\mygadget\gadget.xml
```

If you could post the gadget zip file it could also be helpful.